# Only two-particle Fock states contribute to the decay amplitude - meaning?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, mesons

From the definition of the hadronic decay amplitude $f_h$,
$$
f_h P^\mu=\langle 0 | J^\mu(0)|P\rangle
$$
it follows that it is only the two-particle Fock states which contribute to $f_h$. Indeed, the current $J^\mu(0)$ is just a sum of bilinears in creation and annihilation operators:
$$
J^\mu(0)\sim\left(\sum_k ...b_k+...d^\dagger_k\right)\left(\sum_{k'} ...b_{k'}+...d^\dagger_{k'}\right)
$$
where dots stand for spinors and c-numbers. Therefore, only the two-particle Fock states can be mapped by such an operator onto the vacuum state:
$$
\langle 0|J^\mu(0)|\underbrace{k_1...k_N}_{N\neq2}\rangle = 0
$$

Could anyone explain in simple words the physical meaning of this? Why do the amplitudes of Fock states with the number of particles other than two contain no information about the decay process?

Comment: The current is how the gauge boson couples to matter: it tells you how a symmetry transformation turns one state into another.

Comment: But intuitively it seems that a boson should be able to interact with just one particle from the Fock state - as when we describe DIS within the parton model.

Comment: It sure does: you have line-reversed one of them from the left hand side to the right hand side!